# C# and AWS S3 - receiving ServiceUnavailable error despite only making a single request

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy

The following code is used by software on a server outside AWS to obtain some information from a file within an S3 bucket in Amazon. This data is then broken up and used for other purposes.

```
List<Document> documentList = new List<Document>();
            try
            {
                AmazonS3Config amazonS3Config = new AmazonS3Config();
                amazonS3Config.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(Settings.AWSRegion);

                if (Settings.Proxy == true)
                {
                    if (Settings.IsMasterService == true)
                    {
                        amazonS3Config.ProxyHost = Settings.ProxyHost;
                        amazonS3Config.ProxyPort = Settings.ProxyPort;
                        amazonS3Config.ProxyCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Settings.IsCompanyStore == true)
                        {
                            amazonS3Config.ProxyHost = Settings.ProxyHostCompanyStore;
                            amazonS3Config.ProxyPort = Settings.ProxyPortCompanyStore;

                            NetworkCredential corpProxyCreds = new NetworkCredential(Settings.ProxyUserNameCompanyStore, Settings.ProxyPasswordCompanyStore);
                            amazonS3Config.ProxyCredentials = corpProxyCreds;
                        }
                    }
                }
                AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(amazonCreds, amazonS3Config);

                GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest();
                req.BucketName = Settings.S3BucketName;
                req.Key = Settings.S3ObjectName;
                using (GetObjectResponse response = s3.GetObject(req))
                    if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        using (Stream amazonStream = response.ResponseStream)
                        {
                            StreamReader amazonStreamReader = new StreamReader(amazonStream);
                            string _lne = string.Empty;
                            while ((_lne = amazonStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                string[] _cfglines = _lne.Split('&');
                                foreach (string c in _cfglines)
                                {
                                    string[] _fle = c.Split('|');
                                    Document d = new Document();
                                    d.Name = _fle[1];
                                    d.FolderPath = _fle[0];

                                    documentList.Add(d);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EventHandling.RaiseDebugEvent("response.HttpStatusCode.ToString() = " + response.HttpStatusCode.ToString());
                        throw new Exception("Could not obtain master configuration file. Status: " + response.HttpStatusCode.ToString());
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventHandling.RaiseDebugEvent(" ReturnCloudCaptureDocumentList ex.tostring = " + ex.ToString());
                EventHandling.RaiseEvent(ex.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }

            return documentList;
```

We have two different types of servers outside AWS. One behind a proxy, one not behind a proxy.

On the server not behind a proxy, this code works fine. 
On the server behind a web proxy, this code fails every time with the following error:

> 'Error making request with Error Code ServiceUnavailable and Http
>   Status Code ServiceUnavailable. No further error information was
>   returned by the service.

Reviewing Amazon documentation, the ServiceUnavailable error occurs when you are making too many requests to S3 in a short space of time. This isn't true of this scenario however. We are making only one request, and even if we were making many requests, this would not explain why on one server it works fine, but on another it doesn't (with the only difference being the presence of a Proxy).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: One possibility is that access to the bucket is restricted to the non-proxy'd machine's IP. Another possibility is that your proxy is mangling the request. Yet another possibility is that your proxy is refusing to forward the request.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with no access to the bucket from the Proxy, so thank you :)

Comment: One of you should post it as the answer below to get credit for it, and so people can more easily see what the issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Well shoot, if no one else wants the reputation, I'll take it. ;) )

There are at least three things I can think of (ht to @Collin-Dauphinee).

1. Access to the bucket may be restricted to the non-proxy'd machine's IP.
2. Your proxy may be mangling the request.
3. Your proxy may be refusing to forward the request.